# How to access dynamic id tag with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to update the paragraph tag in foreach with jquery selector in my second ajax call. I made the id tag unique by setting it to `id="spots_,+item.id`" but don't know how to access the dynamic id tag outside the foreach loop. I keep getting "id is not defined" error. Thought maybe a global variable would work but no success.

```
//ajax form the get available times to play
$('#form').submit(function(){
$.ajax({
  url: $('#form').attr('action'),
  type: 'POST',
  data : $('#form').serialize(),
     success: function(response){
      $.each(JSON.parse(response), function(i, item) {
          var jdate = $('#date').val();

        $('<tr>').html("<td>" + item.time + "</td><td>" + '<form class="insideForm" action="/reservations/getSpots" accept-charset="utf-8"  method="">'  + '<input type="text" name="jtime" value="' + item.time + '"' + "/>"  + '<input type="text" name="jdate" value="' + jdate + '"' + ">" + '<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Spots">' +  '</form>' + "</td><td>" + "Spots:" + '<p class="spots" id="spots_' + id + '"'+ ">" + '<div id="spots"></div>' + '</p>'  +  "</td>").appendTo('#availableTimes');
        });//end loop                   

    //ajax form the get available spots/seats 
$('.insideForm').submit(function(){
var form = $(this).closest('form');

$.ajax({
  url: $(this).attr('action'),
  type: 'POST',
  data : $(this).serialize(),
          success: function(response){        
        $('#spots_'+id).html(response);         
      }//end success      
    });
   return false;
});                    
  }//end success
});
return false;
});//end ajax time form
```

Comment: As you have multiple outputs, I think you have to change ID to CLASS in first step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your .insideForm object you only have one .spots classed paragraph.

Try using the jQuery selector inside the form:

```
$('.insideForm').submit(function () {
    var form = $(this).closest('form');

    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        data: form.serialize(),

        success: function (response) {
            $('.spots', form).html(response);
        }//end success

    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: This got rid of the error but still not updating the paragraph tag.

Comment: I edited the code, now the success callback should find the .spots class in the form, which has been submitted.

Comment: Okay. So I moved my paragraph tag inside the form tag  and used your code and it worked! You are a lifesaver. I spent 7 hours trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

In your `$.ajax` call change `url: $(this).attr('action')` to `url: form.attr('action')`.  Inside the callback, `$(this)` refers to the `jqXHR` object of the ajax call, not the element the event handler was bound to.

**EDIT**

I also changed `$(this).serialize()` to `form.serialize()` for the same reason above.

```
//ajax form the get available spots/seats 
$('.insideForm').submit(function() {
  var form = $(this).closest('form');

  $.ajax({
    url: form.attr('action'),
    type: 'POST',
    data: form.serialize(),
    success: function(response) {
      $('#spots_' + id).html(response);
    } //end success      
  });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: I see it now.  Let me edit my post because you also have to change `$(this).serialize()` to `form.serialize()`.

Comment: I updated it as you said with Adams response and it works now. Thanks guys